# change DPI for UI only in firefox

Tags: windows, firefox, windows-8.1, dpi

I have A screen with a high pixel density, so I have the DPI set to 125% in Windows, which makes icons larger but blurry. I would like to lower the DPI for the UI so I can increase the font size with Theme Font & Size Changer leaving me with a smaller UI (more vertical Space :) and crispy icons. Setting `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` (which is what I have tried so far) makes web pages smaller too. How can I do this?

***EDIT:*** I'm using Windows 8.1 64-bit professional

Comment: Why not just zoom in firefox?

Comment: @Raystafarian I used to do this but constantly zooming into web pages isn't a good solution either - it messes with formatting and blurs images

Comment: It is my understanding that DPI is a monitor setting, and must be set globally for the whole screen, without regard for application layer considerations.

Comment: @FrankThomas go and change the value of `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`. You'll see what I mean

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23099849/stop-firefox-dpi-scaling-when-windows-setting-is-at-125

Comment: pixels/px is different from what is traditionally called DPI, in that if your monitor DPI is set at 96 (the standard going back to win9x), then no document you load that specifies a differant DPI can be displayed in its native form. pixels/px is just a ratio of how to interpret the 96ppi in terms of CSS style units like px/em. it still displays in 96ppi, but scales the content up or down in percieved size accordingly. there are still 96 pixels per inch on your screen. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch#Computer_monitor_DPI_standards